# POST a JSON body with the Sails REST Blueprint?

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

In Sails 0.10, the default REST blueprint for a create action seems to only accept a POST with the content of the new item via query parameters.  I also need to support the POSTing of a JSON body to create the item.

So, `POST http://localhost:1337/user?username=George` works just fine, but the following does not:

```
POST http://localhost:1337/user

{
   username: 'George'
}
```

Is this possible with the default blueprint or must I implement this manually?

Answer (score 0):

I was missing the header:
`Content-Type: application/json`

Now it works like a champ!